# Identify MSVC's single-pivot partitioning algorithm

Tags: c++, visual-c++, quicksort, partitioning, introsort

I'm looking at how MSVC implements std::sort, and I can't figure out the partitioning method used.
Here's what I know from the code:

1. It's a variant of introsort, which falls back to insertion sort if the section size is `_ISORT_MAX` or below, and does heapsort if recursive depth reaches 1.5log(N)
2. The pivot selection uses Sedgewick's median-of-3 method from the first, mid, and last element. But if the input is larger than 40, it uses Tukey's ninther instead (take 3 median-of-3s, and get median from them).

However, after getting the pivot, I don't really understand what's being done to partition the container. It's not the popular Hoare's, Lomuto's, or Bentley-McIlroy's partition method that I've seen. This is the point where the partitioning starts:
https://github.com/microsoft/STL/blob/master/stl/inc/algorithm#L7474

If you know what is this partitioning method, please do refer me to any links, paper, etc. A name would be useful too.

Thanks.

Comment: I think the Microsoft link is not good because the code shifts over time. That link currently points a little into the start of  _Inplace_merge_buffer_left()
I think it would be better if you named the function you are interested in. That way if people add or subtracts lines, we can still search for the function

Comment: I also don't think the partition has a name. What it did do was arrange the pivot point to be the middle iterator. Then it grew pivot point into a range both top and bottom, So now you had 2 ranges of unknown elements. It then decreases both by passing over bottom top elements  if they fitted in lower or top or swapping with middle if equal to pivot element or swapping between bottom/top if belonging in the other.
It would return an STL range of pivot elements if all equal.

Comment: What I do know is there is a proof on the Internet that O(2N/3) swaps are necessary to partition. But if using a fat pivot (or Dutch National Flag) it is possible for O(5N/9) to be the maximum number of swaps. I cannot find links to these at the moment

Comment: The function in Microsoft's algorithm you want is _Partition_by_median_guess_unchecked()